# jquery validation bootstrap wizard with chosen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, wizard, jquery-chosen

So I have a bootstrap wizard with one step with some chosen select boxes. I have added ignore: ':hidden:not(select)' to allow jquery validate to validate chosen.

This has made the boxes validate but..not on the right step. It validates all the chosen boxes on every step!

```
var $validator = $("#register").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not(select)',
    rules: {
        country: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
$('#registerwiz').bootstrapWizard({
    'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = index+1;
        var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
        var $valid = $("#register").valid();
        if(!$valid) {
            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#registerwiz').find('.progress-bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
        }
    }
});
```

So I wondered how can I make it only validate the chose boxes on that particular step.

and also if possible make the error warning come under the chosen box not above.

Comment: Since `.validate()` is a _one-time_ initialization of the plugin on your page, you cannot _dynamically_ change the `ignore` option if that's what you're trying to do.  Your settings apply to the entire form and cannot be changed later.  You can only dynamically change the rules using the `.rules('add')` method.  So when you setup the step, add `required` to only the hidden fields you need validated.  Then on the next step, use `.rules('remove')`, etc.

Comment: I somewhat understand what you are saying but I'm finding it very hard to turn it into code. Would I be right to say in the onNext function I have if(index==3) { and add the rule here and } else { remove the rule here }. Would that be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

add errorPlacement

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.is('input[type=checkbox]') || element.is('input[type=radio]')) {
                var controls = element.closest('div[class*="col-"]');
                if (controls.find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 1) controls.append(error);
                else error.insertAfter(element.nextAll('.lbl:eq(0)').eq(0));
            }
            else if (element.is('.select2')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="select2-container"]:eq(0)'));
            }
            else if (element.is('.chosen-select')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="chosen-container"]:eq(0)'));
            }
            else error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
```

it well works

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Just to mention: it must be declared as a property in the object argument passed to the `validate` function, at the same level as `rules`.